# Spring integration scatterGather aggregator is failing to return result

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are updating to the latest version of the spring integration and facing an issue with the aggregator returning a result

ex of transforming strings to upper and lower cases and aggregating them to a list

```
    public IntegrationFlow stringTransformer() {
        return f -> f
                .scatterGather(
                        scatterer -> scatterer
                                .applySequence(true)
                                .recipientFlow(f1 -> f1.<List<String>, List<String>>transform(p -> p.stream().map(String::toUpperCase)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                                .recipientFlow(f2 -> f2.<List<String>, List<String>>transform(p -> p.stream().map(String::toLowerCase)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))),
                        gatherer -> gatherer.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                                .outputProcessor(messageGroup -> {
                                    List<String> finalList;
                                     finalList = messageGroup.getMessages().stream()
                                             .map(Message::getPayload)
                                             .map(p -> (List<String>)p)
                                             .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                    return finalList;
                                }),
                        s -> s.errorChannel("scatterGatherErrorChannel"));
    }
```

`1.2.2` version of `spring-integration-java-dsl` there was nothing to the aggregator and it works fine.

`5.5.2` the code expects/checks if the aggregator is returning of Type `Messages`.

Resulting an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The expected collection of Messages contains non-Message element: class java.lang.String: class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.assignableCheckFailed(Assert.java:720) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:670) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.verifyResultCollectionConsistsOfMessages(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:943) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:902) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
```

MessageGroup is on default correlationStrategy & releaseStrategy for the group.

is there any other flag needs to be set for aggregator not to treat as a Message ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall why that change was needed.

I suggest you add `.map(list -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(list));` after the `.collect()`.

It needs to be Spring Integration's `MessageBuilder` - not the one from spring-messaging.

Comment: is it needed for split or another pattern as well ? haven't tried it yet .. that is some thing we were using heavily.

Comment: Not that I am aware of; it is specific to the output processor result.